# ExtJS multiple view instances

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am trying to add a toolbar of the same type to each tab of a tabpanel.

The problem is, that if I add them in an `afterrender` function(with `add()` and `doLayout()`), I get only one toolbar, on the last created tab.

If I add to each tab the proper `xtype`, so that the toolbar will be added from the beginning, I also get only one instance, which doesn't even gets rendered properly.

How am I supposed to create multiple instances of the same view?

Comment: It appears you have a common case of misconfiguration/creation issue. This is a typical issue if you have created the toolbar using config rather than in initComponent. If you provide the code of how and where the toolbar is added I'm sure we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Also, are you using 4.0.7 or 4.1?

Comment: @Izhaki I am using 4.1, and I have figured out what the problem was: I was using some global buttons upon the creation of the toolbar. That is why they appeared only in the last tab. The toolbar was created, only it got empty. Thank you anyway. :D

Comment: Great. Please post an answer and accept it so this question is marked as answered. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128689/should-the-question-be-closed-if-the-user-found-the-solution-by-himself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the number of instances, but with the way I created the needed buttons: they were global variables. This is why they moved from one toolbar to another, making it seem as if the toolbar itself was gone.